# Saving side of a bidirectional relation

Tags: jpa

In a bidirectional relation, can we do the save from any side?

```
@Entity
public class Department {
  @OneToMany
  private Collection<employee> employees;
  ...
}


@Entity
public class Employee {
   @ManyToOne
   private Department department;
   ...
}
```

can we decide to do

```
departement.setEmployee(employees)
departmentDao.save(departement);
```

and

```
employee.setDepartment(department);
employeeDao.save(employee);
```

Comment: The supposing duplicate question don't respond mine... so please if you said it's a duplicate choose the correct questions/answer

Answer (score 1):

I think that it depends in the type of cascade that you use in your relationship (@ManyToOne, @OneToMany, etc) and in which of your entitys you put it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html